# Cordova serve says 404 not found

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I'm just getting started to cordova.

I've created an application using

```
cordova create androidTest
```

and then

```
cd androidTest

cordova platform add android

cordova prepare

cordova build
```

and at last,

```
cordova serve android
```

which says

```
Static file server running at
  => http://0.0.0.0:8000/
CTRL + C to shutdown
```

When I open it, the only thing I get is:

```
404 Not Found
```

[image: 404 in Cordova]

Why? What am I doing wrong? Did I get the meaning of cordova serve command wrong?

I am supposed to see some kind of "application" that is "rendered" in Chrome, don't I?

*(using 3.1.0-0.1.0 )*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, I got stung by this too.

The correct behaviour now seems to be to just run

```
cordova serve
```

and then you can navigate to

```
localhost:8000/<platform>/www/index.html
```

where platform is 'android' in your case. It doesn't seem to automatically route to index.html any more so you need to include that part of the url explicitly. There's a cordova bug [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4797) although I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: Thanks! That's a huge step for me! Another question, I always thought that, once I  was able to "serve" the files I can use Ripple to emulate phone on Chrome. However, with or without ripple I get this input box: https://www.dropbox.com/s/srfzzn0hscvxt7f/Screenshot%202013-10-08%2019.18.45.png Do you know how can I advance?

Comment: Yes, I get that too. Not had time to investigate fully, but find if I click 'cancel' it works fine.

Comment: But don't forget to press 'cancel' if you get a prompt because otherwise you will get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Clarification:

Cordova launches a server that listens on all available IP addresses on port 8000. That is what the message means when it says it's running on "0.0.0.0:8000". It doesn't mean the server is literally running on 0.0.0.0.

0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP.